# What is the best way to save user progress in a web app?

Tags: dart

Lets say you have a web application that has a feature with multiple steps
(Example, Adding Tax Information, you can relate it to TurboTax).

What would be best way to keep track of the user's progress without changing the URL?

Here are couple of thoughts that I have, but I am sure there are better ones.

- For 5 steps, have 5 sets of urls like www.webapp.com/step1 , www.webapp.com/step2 .... (But, I dont want to change the urls.)
- Or use browser cookies

Comment: Save for what purpose and how long? Should it be available when the user closes the browser and reopens the page to continue where she started?